# What is an example of a sample space in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, conditional-probability, mathematical-statistics

Let $X$ denote a random variable. Then from a rigorous mathematical perspective (books such as Durrett, Feller, Kolmogorov, etc.),

$X$ is a function. $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Domain of the function is the sample space, $\Omega$

Range is a value in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

In supervised learning, let $X, Y$ denote the random variable corresponding to the data $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and target $y_n \in \mathbb{R}$ respectively.

Then $X$ maps from a sample space into a piece of data $x_n$. And $Y$ maps from a sample space into a piece of target, $y_n$.

With this, the notation, such as $p_{X|Y}(x_n|y_n) = \Pr[X = x_n| Y = y_n]$

is completely well defined.

Then we can start talking about things like logistic regression, i.e.,

$p_{X|Y}(x_n|y_n) = \Pr[X = x_n| Y = y_n] = \text{logit}(y_nw^Tx_n) \in (0,1)$

etc.

**But what is the sample space $\Omega$?** Any example would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10789/why-are-random-variables-defined-as-functions